# Multidimensional weighted Paley-Wiener spaces are Hilbert spaces?

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, fourier-analysis, harmonic-analysis, hilbert-spaces, complex-analytic-spaces

How to rigorously demonstrate that multidimensional weighted Paley-Wiener spaces are Hilbert spaces?

I am utilizing the exponential type definition established by Elias Stein in the book 'Fourier Analysis on $n$-dimensional Euclidean Spaces' (Chapter 3, Section 4):

If $F : \mathbb{C}^d \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ is an entire function of $d$ complex variables, which is not identically zero, we say that $F$ has exponential type if
$$
\tau(F) := \limsup_{\|\mathbf{z}\| \rightarrow \infty} \frac{ \log |F(\mathbf{z})|}{\|\mathbf{z}\|} < \infty
$$
(here $\tau(F)$ is the exponentional type of $F$) with
$$
\|\mathbf{z}\| := \sup \left\{ \left|\sum_{n=1}^d z_nt_n\right|; \quad t \in \mathbb{R}^d \text{ and } |t| \leq 1 \right\}.
$$
For each $\alpha > -d$ and $\delta > 0$, we let $H_{\alpha}(d ; \delta)$ be the multidimensional Paley-Wiener space. We define $H_{\alpha}(d ; \delta)$ to be the space of entire functions $F : \mathbb{C}^d \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ of exponential type at most $\delta$ such that
$$
\|F\|_{H_{\alpha}(d;\delta)} := \left( \int_{\mathbb{R}^d} |F(x)|^2 |x|^{\alpha} \, dx \right)^{1/2} < \infty.
$$

I appreciate any help.

Comment: I'm way too lazy to fill in all the details, but plan should be roughly as follows: the only thing we need to show is completeness, that is that any Cauchy sequence converges. For this you essentially need to obtain the pointwise bounds in $\mathbb{C}^d$ with optimal and uniform type bound, which are also uniformly bounded on compacts. Then you will have a locally convergent sequence of entire functions, hence the limit is also entire, and with needed type bound. For this pointwise estimate you would need some sort of Phragmen--Lindelöf estimate, like in a 1-d case.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. The issue lies in the pointwise estimate. I am unable to employ the same techniques used in de Branges spaces here because I lack a reproducing kernel (or at least I am not aware of one in this specific multidimensional case). Moreover, I cannot utilize similar methods from the classical theory of the $d=1$ case because articles in this dimension generally assume that functions are at least $L^2$.

Comment: There is a standard scheme to prove completeness results for suitable normed spaces. Suppose that you have a complete locally space and a family of continuous seminorms which separates points.  Then the supremum  of this set is a norm on the subspace consisting of those vectors for which it is finite.  Not only that, but the corresponding normed space is complete.  A suitable choice of ingredients proves your result.